# Is it possible to do a Facebook status update programatically in .NET?

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm using Twitter's OAuth API to updates a user's twitter account (twitter status update) provided they give permission / authorise my site with their twitter account. works great.

Can the same be done with Facebook?

I was told Facebook connect does this, but all I can find are pages talking about how to make Facebook embedded apps (mini websites that sit INSIDE the facebook application).

I don't want to do anything like that. i just want to allow a user to give my website read/write permissions to their facebook account (authorisation) and then update their facebook status.

Can this be done? Any links to .NET examples?

EDIT: When I say 'status update', does Facebook call this a 'Feed' ? as in, you publish a new feed item?

EDIT 2: Ok, i've tried to look through the web for some scenario examples, to help visualise my problem.

YouTube does this. In YT, when you post a video, you can then update your Facebook status feed thingy automatically ... provided you've given YT permission to do so. Check out this screenie...

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/9734/connectwf.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/9734/connectwf.png)

Notice how YT allows you to give Facebook permission? That's what i'm trying to do.

AND .. (this is important) ... it's a fire-and-forget thing. Once the user clicks on the Facebook Connect linky, authorises, then comes back to the original (my) website, the user never has to authorise, again (this is what Twitter does, btw).

So is this possible? What are the keywords I need to search for, to do this in .NET, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all about the Facebook APIs on their developer website at http://developer.facebook.com/.

Specifically, the [Status.set](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set) method is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I know the link to the facebook dev stuff. I'm hoping to understand some of the concepts. So is facebook Connect the equivalent to Twitters OAuth ? Once i've authorised with Facebook that my website can do stuff, on behalf of the user .. will I get an AccessToken which i can then use to auto-authenticate with Facebook with i do a Status.set thingy?   /me hasn't checked out the doco for Status.set.. just yet ... /me runs off to do that.